# String.format produces weird output

Tags: java, string.format

I need to format a long value to string.

The input record like:

```
"12353555100001112083997OOO0000003   0015900122550300099010000245000311503576L16N000012800001286  01      000179            00000510000492M00058499999    0016000001000541900818901    0045207 00<strong>0003</strong>0000016"
```

I'm doing some manipulation on the bolded 4 char (by converting it to long) and few other manipulations of other characters and produce a result.

The manipulation of `0003` should yield `384` and hence before inserting into the actual record I need to append '0' and should be like `0384`. I used

```
long myValue = 384;
output = record.replace(record.substring(startIndex, endIndex), String.format("%1$4d", myValue));
```

But, it produces a weird output like:

```
1 3845551 3841112083997OOO 384003   00159001225503   9901 384245000311503576L16N 384128 3841286  01      000179             384051 384492M00058499999    0016 38401000541900818901    0045207  38403 384016
```

where i can see, that 384 is inserted multiple times into the record. what could be the error?

Comment: Can you post some code sample? Your so called some manipulations on the char might be messing things up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> where i can see, that 384 is inserted multiple times into the record. what could be the error?

replace will replace all occurrances of the first argument with the second argument.

```
record.replace(record.substring(startIndex, endIndex), String.format("%1$4d", myValue));
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                       first argument                         second argument
```

That is, if the string `record.substring(startIndex, endIndex)` happens to represent a string that occurs in several places in `record` then the second argument will end up in multiple places.

You may want to look at [`StringBuilder.replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#replace%28int,%20int,%20java.lang.String%29), and do something like

```
record.replace(startIndex, endIndex, String.format("%1$4d", myValue));
```

Comment: so wt should i use here to replace, only where i want?

Comment: do something like record = new StringBuilder(record).replace(startIndex, endIndex, String.format(...)).toString()

Comment: One more question @aiobee: i read the records from arraylist<String> and doing the manipulations. As, you have mentioned, I'm using StringBuilder for the manipulations. So, I read the arraylist's record everytime as a 'String' then do this 'new StringBuilder' and do my logics. And, again covert it to 'String' and add to a new ArrayList<String>. Am i doing it right, or doing 'new StringBuilder' is not the right way?

Comment: You can do it with new StringBuilder if you like. Another option would be to use ArrayList<StringBuilder> all the way through.